# How to fetch Transaction details from Razor Pay?

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, payment, mobile-application, razorpay

How to get Payment details(transaction id ,Payment methods etc ) from Razor pay and store on personal Firebase database after capturing the transaction. in Flutter

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about this. But,I could just give you an idea. 
You can just get the transaction details, something like this,

```
Map<dynamic,dynamic> paymentResponse = new Map();
paymentResponse = await FlutterRazorpaySdk.openPaymentDialog(options); // Refer Docs for options
print("response $paymentResponse");
updateDatabase(paymentResponse);
```

and with `updateDatabase()` as like this,

```
updateDatabase(info){
 DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('payments').push();
 reference.set(info).then((res) {
    print("Saved to Database!")
 }).catch((e) {
    print("Error in Saving to Database!");
 });
}
```

Hope this gives you an idea.